# Question on Combined Variations

Tags: education

The answer I got for K is 192 but I felt that was too much. So any help clarifying would be great.

y varies directly with the square root of p and inversely with the square of q. If y=6 when p=4 and q=8. Find y when p=16 and q=4

Comment: What is the difficulty you are facing? Just write the equation that defines "$y$ varies directly with the square root of $p$" and you should be almost done.

Comment: **Welcome to Mathematics Stack Exchange!** A quick [tour](https://math.stackexchange.com/tour) will enhance your experience. Here are helpful tips to [write a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question/9960#9960) and [write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).  For equations, please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Method 1:$$y \ \propto \frac{\sqrt p}{q^2} \implies y = k \frac{\sqrt p}{q^2} $$

At $y=6, p= 4 , q = 8$,

$k = 6\cdot32 = 192$

So at $p = 16, q = 4$

> $ y = k \frac{\sqrt p}{q^2} = 192 \frac{4}{16} = 48$

Method 2: 
$$y \ \propto \frac{\sqrt p}{q^2} \implies  \frac{y_2}{y_1} = \frac{\sqrt{p_2}}{q_2^2} \cdot \frac{q_1^2}{\sqrt{p_1}}$$

$$\frac{y_2}{6} = \frac{4}{16}\cdot\frac{64}{2}=8 \implies y_2 = y = 48$$

Comment: @Matti P. Thanks, I didn't know the MathJax code of *proportional to*